# NLog 5.0.4 does not log exceptions

Tags: c#, nlog

I have the following console application:

```
using NLog;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static Logger logger = null;
        static void Main()
        {
            string targetName = "logconsole";
            logger = LogManager.GetLogger(targetName);
            var _logLayout = "${message} | ${exception:format=tostring} #";
            var _config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
            var _logConsole = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget(targetName) { Layout = _logLayout };
            _config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, _logConsole);

            NLog.LogManager.Configuration = _config;
            CauseException();
        }

        private static void CauseException()
        {
            try
            {
                string s = null;
                bool b = s.Contains('a');
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //Console output: "123 | #"
                logger.Error("123", exc);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

I have included NLog 5.0.4 via NuGet. The logger output does not include any exception details at all, only the message "123" I passed directly to the logger. What I want is the exception details like message, stack trace etc. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the method `Logger.Error<T>(string message, T argument)`. The exception is passed as a argument of the message format (like with String.Format).

To display a exception you need to use `Logger.Error(Exception exception, string message)` like :

```cs
catch (Exception exc)
{
    logger.Error(exc, "123");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-log-exceptions